# I am not able to put values in the elements of a dynamically allocated array with scanf?

Tags: c

What can I do to assign values to the elements of the array that is being called from the heap memory. I want to take the values from the user, so I was using scanf here but as I try to assign the first value to the first element of the array the compiler shows a segmentation fault(core dumped) and i am not able to assign further values.

```
 int n,i;
 int *num;
 int answer = 1;

scanf("%d", &n);

num = (int*)(malloc(n*sizeof(int)));

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", num[i]);
    answer = (answer*num[i])%(((int)pow(10,9))+7);
}

printf("\n%d",answer);
free(num);
return 0;
```

I want to assign the values to all the elements of the array that will be user defined both the array size and the values inside the array.

Comment: `scanf("%d", num[i]);` -> `scanf("%d", &num[i]);`

Comment: instead of `pow(10,9)+7` it'll be easier to read with `1e9 + 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` requires an address to place the scanned input into.  You are providing a value, not an address to the value.

To understand this better, to print the number, you would reference it as `num[i]`, but to get the address of that same number, you would use `&num[i]`.